# Using Excel as calculate engine

Tags: java, python, excel

I have 10 different excel sheet that came from a different provider, fully formulated.
All of them get 10 item as input and give us 4 item as an output.
Is it possible that we prepare a web page to get this 10 item from the clients, then set to excel files, run the excels and show output on the web?Actullay I want to use to Excel files as a calculator engine.
Thank you, guys. Let me explain more
1. each excel sheet has more than 10 sheets full formulate and a BA need minimum 2 days to analyse it.
2. between 10 days to 3 months, providers changed the formula, and it's tough to find which part changed
3. we think the best solution is to keep Excel sheet as calculate engine because if provider changed, we could use new excel file.
4. input and output items never change.

Comment: Excel is not the correct tool for this type of task. I suggest learning something like Python or PHP, finding an Excel import library that you like, extracting the data, doing the relevant processing, and then displaying the results on a webpage. If you wanted to use Excel you would have to do all of the work manually yourself, for the rest of your life.

Comment: try using Apache POI - you can certainly input amounts to excel and *run* its formulas

Comment: How about Google Sheets?

Comment: Thank you, guys. Let me explain more
1. each excel sheet has more than 10 sheets full formulate and a BA need minimum 2 days to analyse it.
2. between 10 days to 3 months, providers changed the formula, and it's tough to find which part changed
3. we think the best solution is to keep Excel sheet as calculate engine because if provider changed, we could use new excel file.
4. input and output items never change.

Answer (score 2):

As a general notion, everything is possible. The question is whether you really want this because it sounds to me like you're going to have a hard time making this site anywhere near pleasantly fast.

To let Excel do the calculations, you have to open the workbook file in Excel. This can be automated via VBA or a COM interface, for which Python and Java have libraries available.

However, I reckon that you will need less time to learn a new programming language, implement the Excel features you desire in that language and then hook that code up in your server, than you will need to get the COM interface properly working.

Comment: why not have a jsp/servlet website with the servlet opening the spreadsheet using apache poi, running its formula and returning the answer to the website - I am doing exactly this

Comment: Apache POI uses Microsofts' OLE tech to access office files, which lives on top of the COM, so your solution is an example what I described.

Comment: Please explain how I am able to run it on RHEL then.

Comment: As per their webpage *Apache POI is also the master project for developing pure Java ports of file formats based on Office Open XML*

Comment: You're right, the Apache POI project also hosts Java ports of the Office standards. @user7811959 however specifically said he wanted to use Excel as the engine, so I guess your specific solution isn't applicable to his problem after all.

Comment: as a *calculator engine* Let me explain how I am using in a very busy production environment.  Every minute a receive a couple of files with thousands of double values, these files are received via ftp, parsed and the values are input from a servlet into xls using POI.  Complex (and subject to change) computations are done on the input values and the result values are then retrieved sored in a DB and output to a web apge.

Comment: Thank you, guys. Let me explain more
1. each excel sheet has more than 10 sheets full formulate and a BA need minimum 2 days to analyse it.
2. between 10 days to 3 months, providers changed the formula, and it's tough to find which part changed
3. we think the best solution is to keep Excel sheet as calculate engine because if provider changed, we could use new excel file.
4. input and output items never change.